# PRISM for silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, prism

Can I use prism 5 for Silverlight 5 applications?
I have used prism 4.1 already, but I wonder if it worth it or not.

Comment: Silverlight is not supported in Prism 5 or up.

Answer (score 0):

Although a bit outdated (as it doesn't list Prism 6), [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648465.aspx) shows what versions are supported for which targeted framework. So you'll have to keep using **Prism 4.1** for Silverlight 5. There are new newer versions supporting Silverlight.